# how to test mvc controller for status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm using the native .net visual studio testing tools for my controller.  Trying to make sure that at this point (very beginning of code) I'm getting an unauthorized status code set if what is passed to the controller doesn't pass authorization.  Here's my controller code.

```
public class HubspotController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FreeDemo(string json)
    {
        JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(json);

        var password = jobject["person"]["password"]?.ToString();
        var username = jobject["person"]["username"]?.ToString();

        if (!AuthorizeUser(password, username))
        {
            StatusUnauthorized();
        }

        var resultStatus = new ResultStatus { Message = "success"};
        return Json(resultStatus, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult StatusUnauthorized()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized");
    }

    private bool AuthorizeUser(string password, string username)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is my test.  Bear with me, I don't have much testing experience so just trying to figure this out.

```
[TestClass]
public class HubspotControllerFixture
{
    private Mock<HttpRequestBase> request;
    private Mock<HttpContextBase> httpContext;
    private Mock<HttpResponseBase> response;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        request.SetupGet(r => r.ContentType).Returns("application/json");
        response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        httpContext.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Status_Code_Gets_Set_To_Unauthorized()
    {
        var json = "{\"person\": {\"password\":\"abc123\", \"username\":\"user\", \"name\":\"test person\"}}";
        var controller = new HubspotController()
        {
            ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
            {
                HttpContext = httpContext.Object
            }
        };
        controller.FreeDemo(json);
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, httpContext.Object.Response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the error.  What am I doing wrong?

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:`<Unauthorized
>   (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)>`. Actual:`<0 (System.Int32)>`.

Comment: I doubt you can use the http context in the tests as you're not really in a request/response scenario in your test code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asserting the wrong object in your test. This test case has no effect or dependency on HttpContext. You would want to assert the result of your method under test.

You first need to update your target controller action.

```
//...other code omitted for brevity
if (!AuthorizeUser(password, username))
{
    return StatusUnauthorized();
} 
//...other code omitted for brevity
```

And your Test would now look like this as You actually don't need the mocked HttpContext for this test case

```
[TestMethod]
public void Status_Code_Gets_Set_To_Unauthorized() {
    //Arrange
    var json = "{\"person\": {\"password\":\"abc123\", \"username\":\"user\", \"name\":\"test person\"}}";
    var controller = new HubspotController();
    var expected = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    //Act
    var actionResult = controller.FreeDemo(json) as HttpStatusCodeResult;
    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actionResult.StatusCode);
}
```

Comment: I wondered about that but seeing as how what was returned was 0 and not 401 I figured the problem was deeper.  But I updated the assert anyway.  Now I get Expected:<401>. Actual:<0>

Comment: It is deeper as well. the fact that it is `0` also shows that you are comparing the wrong thing

Comment: Note, this will not work if you're returning Json/View because they cannot cast to HttpStatusCodeResult.

Comment: This is meant to test a specific scenario. It will obviously not work for what you indicated and would have to be refactored for its particular test case

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a return statement.  See updated code below.

```
public class HubspotController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FreeDemo(string json)
    {
        JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(json);

        var password = jobject["person"]["password"]?.ToString();
        var username = jobject["person"]["username"]?.ToString();

        if (!AuthorizeUser(password, username))
        {
            return StatusUnauthorized();
        }

        var resultStatus = new ResultStatus { Message = "success"};
        return Json(resultStatus, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult StatusUnauthorized()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized");
    }

    private bool AuthorizeUser(string password, string username)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see that.  However even when adding that return statement in I get the same error/failure.